# replacing "connected" with a more informal word

Tags: word-choice

Need help replacing "connected" with a more informal word in the following line:

"Preeti connected with neighbors on Chats and Discussions."

Connected to me sounds like a very "enterprise" term.

Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks Jim. "chatted" doesn't go with discussions. Need to highlight feature of chat and general discussion. Something less informal than "hooked up" is what I am looking for.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. How about *associated*? *Talked*? Bonded (a cliche now)? Befriended? *Kept in touch with*? *Kept up with*?

Comment: Is "Chats and Discussions" a name for something? I ask only because you have used capital letters. Is the example sentence to be used as a title?

Comment: Chats and Discussions are names of features of the website, this content is going on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use "be in touch" or (depending on the context) "get in touch":

> "Preeti was in touch with neighbors on Chats and Discussions"
>
> "Preeti got in touch with neighbors on Chats and Discussions"

Comment: "stays in touch" sounds good ..

Answer (score 1):

*Connect* is not an (overly-) 'enterprise' term.

It is the right word for the context.

> *Enjoy the sun! **Connect** with neighbors!* It's warm outside, and that means time for summer community events, summer concerts, and street fairs.
>
> In an age of technology so vastly consuming our every moment of free time, it can be difficult to **connect** with neighbors on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

> Preeti **met** with neighbors on Chats and Discussions.

Answer (score 0):

> Preeti **synched** with neighbors on Chats and Discussions."

Answer (score 0):

Preeti **made friends** with neighbors on Chats and Discussions

Alternatively:

- *hung out with*
- *mixed with*

Comment: I think it ought to be *hung out* with.